# ¿Cómo valido que si una fecha es mayor a la actual, se realize un update?

Tags: sql

tengo la siguiente consulta .
Quiero hacer un update a todas las actividades que su fecha de fin, sea menor a la actual, y que su estado pase a ser 'Finalizado',Tengo realizado esto :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Que es lo que está mal? Cuando ejecuto la consulta, no se realizan cambios.

Comment: En primera. ¿Por que usas `%e` y `%c` en lugar de `%d` y `%m`? ¿Consideras el día 0  como el primer día del mes? ¿Consideras enero como mes 0? Ninguna de las fechas que muestras es menor que la fecha actual. Esa es la razón por la que no se acrualizan. Usa por favor `date_format(now(), %d/%m/%Y)`.

Comment: Ok gracias!!!!!!!